# Firebase App Distribution (fastlane plugin): could not generate credentials from the refresh token

Tags: android, firebase, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

The problem is I can not authorise in Firebase **(App Distribution could not generate credentials from the refresh token specified)**. I got an error:

```
App Distribution could not generate credentials from the refresh token specified.
Refresh token used: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXfE-VQ" (redacted)
Authorization failed.  Server message:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
Response status: 400

+------+------------------------------------+-------------+
|                    fastlane summary                     |
+------+------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                             | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                   | 0           |
| 2    | :app:assembleSkRelease             | 5           |
| 3    | Switch to android defineGroup lane | 0           |
| 4    | Switch to android distributeFB     | 0           |
|      | lane                               |             |
|    | firebase_app_distribution          | 0           |
+------+------------------------------------+-------------+
```

I tried to generate new refresh token via firebase plugin: `bundle exec fastlane run firebase_app_distribution_login` several times, but there is no effect. I checked that I correctly setup new `$FIREBASE_TOKEN` in my environment.

Plugin info:

```
+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+
|                                    Used plugins                                     |
+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+
| Plugin                              | Version | Action                              |
+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+
| fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distr  | 0.3.3   | firebase_app_distribution,          |
| ibution                             |         | firebase_app_distribution_add_test  |
|                                     |         | ers,                                |
|                                     |         | firebase_app_distribution_get_late  |
|                                     |         | st_release,                         |
|                                     |         | firebase_app_distribution_get_udid  |
|                                     |         | s,                                  |
|                                     |         | firebase_app_distribution_login,    |
|                                     |         | firebase_app_distribution_remove_t  |
|                                     |         | esters                              |
+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the value you're setting to $FIREBASE_TOKEN is the one that's printed in the terminal after you enter the code from the website, not this last one.

Comment: Omg, it was my mistake. I think, that I tried to use the code from browser as a refresh token but not a code that I received in terminal. Thank you :)

Comment: I think it threw me off since it was the same token as before - but it makes sense the refresh token was refreshed! Thanks